# Where can I find a tutorial on how to mine with Monero?

Tags: cpu-mining, mining

I would like to mine monero with my i7 cpu or do I need a gpu? Is there a good tutorial on how to go about mining monero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both CPU and GPU can mine monero but GPU is much faster. The best  way to get started with monero mining is by joining a mining pool and following the getting started guide.

Here is a list of mining pools you can join taken from https://www.monero.how/ . I myself is mining at supportxmr.com which is a small pool.

> monero.crypto-pool.fr
>   minexmr.com
>   xmr.prohash.net
>   moneropool.com
>   monerohash.com
>   supportxmr.com
>   xmrpool.net
>   monero.miner.center
>   xmrpool.eu
>   usxmrpool.com 
>   xmr.poolto.be
>   sheepman.mine.bz

The second way you can mine is through solo mining. You need to have a full node and the GUI or CLI wallet. In GUI wallet you just need to click the start mining button while in the CLI you have to type the start_mining command.